# load custom CSS/JS for each CKEditor instance on page

Tags: wysiwyg

I would like to find out  the best way to load custom CSS/JS for each textarea with [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor). For me, each Content Type has different CSS/JS and I would like to load them with the CKEditor on that particular page.

How do I hook into the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module to do just that?

P.S [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) is an independent module and not part of WYSIWYG Drupal Setup.

Answer (score 0):

use `hook_page_build` to add or remove css or js files to the page based on the url. See the examples module for developers on how to add/remove js or css and to examples of render arrays.

your question is not so much about the CKeditor module or WYSIWYG module -- just how to customize css and js on specific criteria such as the page url.

Comment: Thank you tenken. The CSS/JS added to the Content Page do not apply to the content of textarea of CKEditor..How to apply the same CSS/JS of the page to the content of the textarea? Thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934398/ckeditor-issue-how-to-apply-custom-css-to-ckeditor